# What path will santa take?

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge

### Question

Santa must get to every house in the world to deliver gifts, can you make a program that will calculate the shortest path that Santa could take, and still visit all the cities listed?

### Specifications

The program should accept Santa's starting point as input. That could either be a city or a pair of coordinates. That is where it differs from other challenges. Has to return a list of cities in the order that Santa should visit them. The country where the city is located does not have to be outputted. Also assume that air currents and geographical features do not slow Santa down. After Santa has delivered all his presents, we don't need to calculate his path for him anymore(he doesn't have to return home in the program).

```
example input:
Washington D.C.

Example Output:
Tokyo
Delhi
Shanghai
etc.(This output is not correct)
```

### Cities

To make this easier, the program only has to calculate the shortest path between all capital cities of countries [listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order).

### The Winner

This is not intended to be code golf, but if more than one program returns the correct answer, than the shortest program that works will be selected as the winner. If multiple programs work and are the same(shortest) length, the one that was submitted first will be counted as the winner. If you are stuck, Nuuk(northernmost capital) is the first city.

Comment: Does the program even have to calculate anything for this problem? What if someone were to hard-code the list of cities to visit?

Comment: Is this not just the [Traveling Salesman Problem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) Mind, with a bit more Holiday Spirit.

Comment: This is exactly the traveling salesman problem

Comment: Additionally, Nuuk (Greenland) is further north by 0.03°

Comment: The shortest solution is probably to hardcode the output, except maybe in mathematica. A more interesting challenge might be to take Santa's start point as arguments.

Comment: I took your suggestion. Sorry about my geography mistake.